# Racket: inner reduction vs. lazy evaluation?

Tags: racket, lazy-evaluation, evaluation

I thought racket does inner reduction always for evaluation but I found out e.g. "if" (and cond?!) is lazy evaluation in racket...why is this needed?

Is it impossible to realize an if-statement via inner reduction?

I can not figure out where lazy evaluation is better than inner and vice versa? Could someone supply an example?

Comment: For lazy evaluation you have `#!lazy` which is a [lazy racket language](http://docs.racket-lang.org/lazy/) very similar to `#!racket`. Since `#!lazy` is lazy, `if` and other special forms you know from `#!racket` are just plain procedures in `#!lazy`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`if` and `cond` are not "lazy", they just have different evaluation rules. For example, in the following expression only the *consequent* part of the `if` is executed, because the *condition* happens to be `true`:

```
(if (= 1 1)
    'ok
    (/ 1 0))
=> 'ok
```

If the *alternative* part were executed, we'd have a division by zero error. This is not lazy evaluation, it's just the way an `if` expression works in Scheme. Compare the above example with this one:

```
(define (my-if condition consequent alternative)
  (if condition
      consequent
      alternative))

(my-if (= 1 1) 'ok (/ 1 0))
=> /: division by zero
```

Now we're using the standard evaluation rules for procedures, which in a non-lazy interpreter specify that all the arguments are evaluated before executing the procedure's body - hence an error is raised. *That's* why `if` can not be implemented as a normal procedure, it has to be a special form because it requires different evaluation rules.

Comment: Also note that `cond` is not special, since it just macro-expands to `if` expressions.